# awk print syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: awk

print this with awk

```
 ;awk '0==x[$1 FS $2]++' FS="," file4 > file5 ;sed '/fred/d' file5 > file6 ;awk -F/ '{print $5; print $0}' < file6 > new-file.txt ;awk 'NR % 2 { sub("-.*", "") } { print }' < new-file.txt > test ;awk 'NR % 2 { sub("fred.", "") } { print }' < test > test1

# edited for for clarity :
;awk '0==x[$1 FS $2]++' FS="," file4 > file5 
sed '/fred/d' file5 > file6     
awk -F/ '{print $5; print $0}' < file6 > new-file.txt 
awk 'NR % 2 { sub("-.*", "") } { print }' < new-file.txt > test 
awk 'NR % 2 { sub("fred.", "") } { print }' < test > test1
```

to the end of every line in file1

guess i need to escape some of it but what
to start with i have tried to print to a empty file
but get 
syntax error near unexpected token

in file1 each line ends with file4
so could use that as a reference point

Comment: Please add small sample input data, expected output and exact text of error message. Also not clear why there is a leading `;` char at the front of your cmds (it's not needed), but I've left it in place to do the least amt of changes to your string of code, to something that is legible.

Comment: the ; in all the line above  is needed this is the 2nd part of a script the ; makes the script continue to the next step

Comment: it's not needed for the code you have posted. You can always put it back in when you're joining the first (invisible) part of the script, with the visible part (above) ;-) . Still need sample input data, and expected output. Good luck.

Comment: the ; in all the line above  is needed this is the 2nd part of a script the ; makes the script continue to the next step why have you removed all the ; from that line just want to print that line above to the end of every line  in another file which is file1 at the end of every line in file1 is the word file4 so when that line above is printed it will look like this bla bla file4 line above

Comment: you dont need to see all of the first part ot the script just want to print that line i posted to the end of every line in file1 at the end of  every line in file 1 is the word file4 so it looks like this                                           ist-part-of-script file4  ;awk '0==x[$1 FS $2]++' FS="," file4 > file5 ;sed '/fred/d' file5 > file6 ;awk -F/ '{print $5; print $0}' < file6 > new-file.txt ;awk 'NR % 2 { sub("-.*", "") } { print }' < new-file.txt > test ;awk 'NR % 2 { sub("fred.", "") } { print }' < test > test1

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here. Am I alone? I get the sense everyone is avoiding this question because it's not at all clear. Your follow up explanations are equally confounding. Input files and expected output would help, as would some punctuation.

Comment: Read [ask] then try again. Pay particular attention to the part about creating a [mcve].

Comment: i want to print the line i posted as it is with nothing taken out to another file that file is called file1 i want to print the line i posted to the end of every line in file1

Comment: OK. Follow the advice provided in the above comments if you'd like help with any aspect of doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat file
text1
text2
text3

$ awk -v v=" ;awk '0==x[\$1 FS \$2]++' FS=\",\" file4 > file5 ;sed '/fred/d' file5 > file6 ;awk -F/ '{print \$5; print \$0}' < file6 > new-file.txt ;awk 'NR % 2 { sub(\"-.*\", \"\") } { print }' < new-file.txt > test ;awk 'NR % 2 { sub(\"fred.\", \"\") } { print }' < test > test1" '{ print $0 v }' file 

text1 ;awk '0==x[$1 FS $2]++' FS="," file4 > file5 ;sed '/fred/d' file5 > file6 ;awk -F/ '{print $5; print $0}' < file6 > new-file.txt ;awk 'NR % 2 { sub("-.*", "") } { print }' < new-file.txt > test ;awk 'NR % 2 { sub("fred.", "") } { print }' < test > test1
text2 ;awk '0==x[$1 FS $2]++' FS="," file4 > file5 ;sed '/fred/d' file5 > file6 ;awk -F/ '{print $5; print $0}' < file6 > new-file.txt ;awk 'NR % 2 { sub("-.*", "") } { print }' < new-file.txt > test ;awk 'NR % 2 { sub("fred.", "") } { print }' < test > test1
text3 ;awk '0==x[$1 FS $2]++' FS="," file4 > file5 ;sed '/fred/d' file5 > file6 ;awk -F/ '{print $5; print $0}' < file6 > new-file.txt ;awk 'NR % 2 { sub("-.*", "") } { print }' < new-file.txt > test ;awk 'NR % 2 { sub("fred.", "") } { print }' < test > test1
```

Comment: whys it printing print ; print /bin/bash  supose to be print $5; print $0

Comment: Edited to also escape the `$`s.

Comment: If you enclosed the string in single instead of double quotes and just dealt with the single quotes inside the string then you wouldn't have to escape multiple other characters. Just sayin'... Not that I'd actually suggest doing this of course.